# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springfamework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver

Tags: java, spring, maven-2

I am getting this exception even if I can see the CookieLocaleResolver was added in my Library.

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more information. How are you running the application? How are you deploying?

Comment: I am running it in tomcat 7 and deploying it using Maven(mvn clean install) and in my spring-servlet.xml for locale I have mentioned       <bean id="lacaleResolver" class="org.springfamework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver"> 
  <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" /> 
 </bean>

Comment: How did you defined your libraries? Are they maven dependencies? If the answer is yes, what's the scope of the dependency to spring-webmvc-3.0.5-RELEASE?

Comment: I didn't mention any scope.